# Samba shared printers are listed as empty string named on Windows 7's Domain Admins

Tags: samba, file-sharing, smb, printer

I have shared a printer using SMB 3.6.23 service and CUPS Web interface.

Then the printer works just fine, but at a certain point (possibly, while the printer driver is available on Windows 7 using a TCP/IP port printer), the I use

```
rpcclient -U adminac%adminpw -c 'enumprinters 2' 127.0.0.1 | grep -F '[\\127.0.0.1\]' -B 1 -A 2
    servername:[\\127.0.0.1]
    printername:[\\127.0.0.1\]
    sharename:[MyPrinter]
    portname:[]
```

but

```
smbclient -L 127.0.0.1 -N | grep MyPrinter
```

gives an answer.

As can be seen here over, things are as if, `servername` concatenated with `sharename` is not `printername` as expected.  As a result, printer can be listed both by Windows7 file explorer and smbclient, but printer cannot be seen in the `View remote printers` (A empty sting printer appears instead and a exception is rizen while trying to admin this empty string printer.).

How can I get the printer manageable again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use rpcclient anonymously to get a list of problematic printer :

```
nrpclient -U "" -N -c 'enumprinters' 127.0.0.0 \
| grep -F '[\\127.0.0.1\]' -B 1 -A 2
```

Rename printer with a printer manager account, you may want to rename to the same name.

```
rpclient -U adminAccountName%adminAcountPW -c 'setprintername MYPRINT MYPRINT'
```

Done